# Can you play Minecraft Java edition on MacOS?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to know before I buy the game, can I play Minecraft Java Edition on a Mac Book?

Comment: This is easily searchable online - please do your research before posting on Arqade!

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

Yes - go [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/store/minecraft-java-edition) to buy Minecraft!